# Belt moving on two wheels of different radii

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, angular-velocity

I am working on the problem

> A wheel of radius 0.1m (Wheel A) is attached to a wheel of radius 0.2m (Wheel B) by a non-stretching belt which doesn't slip. By the time wheel B turn through 1 revoltion, will wheel B will rotate through?

I am confused about the relation between the wheels' angular velocities and velocities. Will both be twice for A as compared to B?

Comment: The belt must move at the same velocity over each wheel since it doesn't slip. Hence since $ v=r \omega $, the angular velocity of A is twice that of B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with a bike, this is how the gear ratio works!

The velocity of the chain is the same on both wheel, as it doesn't slip.

The velocity of the wheel's border is given by
$$v = R\omega$$
With R the radius, $\omega$ the angular speed,

As the chain doesn't slip

$$R_A\omega_A = v_A = v_B = R_B\omega_B$$

So
$$\frac{\omega_A}{\omega_B} = \frac{R_B}{R_A} = 2$$